# how to handle json response from NSDictionay

Tags: ios, json

I have parsed a json url and saved the json result in NSDictionary result. My parsed result in dictionary is like this:

```
 result : >>>>>>> {
        videos =     (
                    {
                title = "1";
                videolink = "http://dittotv.cdn.bitgravity.com/cdn-_definst_v/secureplaylist.m3u8?e=1402470360&a=IN&h=1f7eba1cb9103525741581eac8e9347c";
            },
                    {
                title = "2";
_definst_v/secureplaylist.m3u8?e=1402470360&a=IN&h=98fc70f984c2624c4f2ba09ba017a7b6";
            },
                    {
                title = "3";
                videolink = "http://dittotv.cdn.bitgravity.com/cdn-_definst_/secureplaylist.m3u8?e=1402470360&a=IN&h=23ee1c3ede6088a50c565aa734439818";
            },
                    {
                title = "4";
                videolink = "http://dittotv.cdn.bitgravity.com/cdn-_definst_/secureplaylist.m3u8?e=1402470360&a=IN&h=b4c400342b59639ad69f837033e66dc1";
            }
        );
    }
```

Now i want the title 4's videolink to open in a web view.
How can i get that videolink in some string so that i can pass that string to the web view.

code is:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

    NSError *myError = nil;

   NSDictionary *results=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    if (data != nil) {


        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"response is %@",jsonString);

        NSLog(@"result : >>>>>>> %@", results);
        if([results objectForKey:@" videolink"])
        {
            [singleton sharedobject].urlid = [results objectForKey:@"videolink"];

            NSLog(@"userid: %@",[singleton sharedobject].urlid);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is basic `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` data access.

Comment: i m not getting title 4's videlink in string

Comment: Post your relevant code so we can help.

Comment: yes post your code. have you retrieved an array through response ?

Comment: not an array but a dictionary

Comment: you should check my code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSString *status = [[[[json valueForKeyPath:@"videos"] objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"videolink"] stringValue];
```

Comment: the value of status string is coming null

Comment: Actually it is valueForKeyPath. check now.

Comment: Divide the second line. first log the [json valueForKeyPath:@"results.videos"]. and check next steps there after.

Comment: now i m getting all the four links in one string out of that i only want the last string.how to get the last link

Comment: @pooja_1205, please check my answer. It will work for you. If your dictionary name is `results` as in your question, just replace `videos` with `results` in my answer.

Comment: id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSString *status = [[[[results valueForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"videolink"] stringValue];
    valueForKey:@"videolink"] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"a string%@",status);

Comment: @pooja_1205 : Store that output in array and do the rest.

Comment: @ DipakSonara:have done that also but all the urls are coming in the array,wen i try object atIndex it says index oy of beyonds,wen i try lastOject of array then also all the 4 url are there

Answer (score -1):

If your NSDictionary variable is named `videos`, then accessing the 4th element is as simple as:

```
[(NSArray*)videos objectAtIndex:3];// will return a smaller dictionary of the superset
```

If you want to access the property `videolink` at the 4th index:

```
[[(NSArray*)videos objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"videolink"]; // will return a string
```

This code will work assuming your dictionary structure (key names etc) is known beforehand.

Comment: Care to explain why? NSDictionaries can be type cast as Arrays when they're composed of nested dictionaries.
I also tested the code with some sample JSON before posting my answer.

Comment: Alternately, since the `NSJSONSerialization +JSONObjectWithData` method returns an `id`, the result can be stored in an NSArray named videos.
Either way, my code works.

Comment: 1) If `videos` is an `NSDictionary`, then casting it to `NSArray` and calling `objectAtIndex:` on the `NSDictionary` will cause a crash. 2) Use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:` to get an object from a dictionary`. 3) You don't show where `videos` comes from. The user has `results`.

Comment: @rmaddy 
1) like I told you, I tested my code before posting the answer.
You're wrong about the `objectAtIndex` causing a crash. Whether an NSDictionary can be cast as an NSArray or not depends on the structure of the NSDictionary. 2) `valueForKey` works fine when you know the dictionary is storing strings. 3) Check the NSLog of the JSON in the question: it is an object named `videos`.

Comment: Look at the code in your answer. You state that `videos` is an `NSDictionary`. If this is the case, then calling `objectAtIndex:` will cause a crash. The only way it won't crash is if your `videos` object is really an `NSArray`. If that's the case, then don't claim it's an `NSDictionary` and don't needlessly cast it to an `NSArray`. `valueForKey:` should only be used when you need to use KVC. If you simply want a direct value from a dictionary, use `objectForKey:`.

Comment: @rmaddy,
Yes, the `videos` is an `NSDictionary`, and depending on its structure, it can indeed be cast as an `NSArray` to call `objectAtIndex`. If you're interested, I will PM you my test code that you can quickly run, it will execute and print its result using `NSLog`.

Comment: Here you go: `NSString *json = @"[{\"title\": \"1\",\"videolink\" : \"video1\"},{\"title\": \"2\",\"videolink\" :\"video2\"}]";

    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *videos = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    
    NSLog(@"JSON:\n %@\n", videos);
    
    NSLog(@"\nvideolink at index 1: %@\n", [[(NSArray*)videos objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"videolink"]);`

Comment: `videos` will actually be an array regardless of the fact that you declare it as an `NSDictionary`. Look at the JSON. The root is an array, not a dictionary. That's why you can call `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: But hasn't that been known all this time? The JSON the user posted is an array. It is parsed into an NSDictionary.
However NSDictionary does not respond to `objectAtIndex`, that's why the type casting was necessary.
I agree the code is cleaner if the assignment is done to an `NSArray` to start off with, but the point is, there will be no crash.

Comment: Use the right data type for the data. The root data is an `NSArray`. You chose to use `NSDictionary` for some unknown reason. That's wrong. Your answer is wrong as written even if it doesn't crash.

Comment: Yes, in my applications, I did always use `NSArray` when that's what the JSON represents. This usage is interesting to note how Objective-C data types work. `NSJSONSerialization +JSONObjectWithData` returns an `id`, and irrespective of the receiving datatype, the `id` instance remains the same.
BUT, let's not claim "the app will crash", when it won't. And let's not claim "this is mostly incorrect" when it is not: it solves the QP's problem exactly as expected of it.